# How can I restore the Files app to original settings?

Tags: settings, pantheon-files, files, default

elementary OS 5.1.4 Hera
Dual-Core Intel® Core™ i7-3537U CPU @ 2.00GHz

This is what happened:

1-After using Inkscape for a while, the image thumbnails disapeared from my system folders.

2-Following an advise, I cleared the cache in $HOME/.cache/thumbnails and $HOME/.thumbnails, using sudo rm -rf *, as per thread: 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2390636

3-Reeboted and the Files app shortcuts to Images, Documents, etc were gone.

4-Navigating to my Home folder and my user with the Files app, there were no thumbnails for any file, the folders all look empty. But hovering shows they have the normal size. On an external drive all is fine, and I got thumbnails back.

5-I restored the settings and reebooted, but the problem remains the same. And my keyboard now also is the wrong one, even though I chose the correct language and region PT, and reebooted yet again.

6-Also, I reinstalled Pantheon using the App Store, and reeboted and the issue remains. Finally, I launched Pantheon with sudo, and it-s exactely the same problem.

So please, I would really apreciate if someone coul help me:
- Get back to normal navigation, in my File System
- If possible, also choose the correct keyboard

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Just clearing the thumbnail caches should not have had such drastic consequences.  Using `sudo rm -rf *` is *very* dangerous as it obliterates *everything* in and below the current folder, including system files, without warning.  It should virtually never be used and then only if you are sure what you are doing.  If you ran it in the wrong folder by mistake then you may have to restore your home folder from back up, if you have one, or reinstall the system - after backing up all you data of course!

Comment: If you looked in `~/.cache` you would have seen a lot of files that have nothing to do with Files - which will now be gone.  If you need to clear the Files thumbnail cache you just need to navigate into both subdirectories `~/.thumbnails` press `<Ctrl>A` to select all files then `Del` to trash them.

Comment: I cannot backup anything. My user folder, had 4GB, and I was able to copy it to my external drive. But when I open it in my external drive, it looks empty. I will format my PC, since this thing with the keyboard is also driving me nuts. Thank you so much for your advice. And I will never use sudo rm -rf * like that again.

Answer (score 0):

To restore Files original settings you can run `sudo apt purge pantheon-files` to remove most of the Files configuration files. It will not remove those in your home directory that were created by running the program such as your bookmarks or color tag database but you probably want to keep those. Then reinstall it with `sudo apt install pantheon-files` (after doing `sudo apt update` to make sure you get the latest released version).

However, I fear from your description that you have deleted a lot of unrelated files as well which cannot simply be restored unless you have a backup of your home folder.

To restore the whole system default settings open Switchboard and navigate to the "About" plug.  There is a button "Restore Default Settings". Again, this may not work if important files have been deleted.

Comment: Thank you for the try. I had already reinstalled using the elementary OS Softwrae center. Anyway, I did try like you said, through terminal and reeboted. It s the same. Same problem.